# How make authentiation laravel with deferent table default

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3, guard

I have database `radius` with table `radcheck` without migration. I want table `radcheck` as table authentication,not users.i try change `config/auth` from 'user' to `radcheck`. but an error

Table `radcheck`:

```
id,
username,
attribute,
op,
value=> as password,
barcode
```

Code in `radcheck.php`:

```
namespace App\Model\Management;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Radcheck extends Model
{

  protected $table = 'radcheck';
  protected $primarykey = 'id';
  protected $fillable = ['id','username','attribute','op','value','barcode'];
  public $timestamps = false;
  public function radusergroups(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Management\Radusergroup');
  }
}
```

and then, I change config/auth from users to radcheck in `Config/auth`:

```
  'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Model\Management\Radcheck::class,
    ],
```

Error looks like this:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Model\Management\Radcheck given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-access\system\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 385 and defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EloquentUserProvider` accept only the instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` so you need to extends your RadCheck by `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

Just change your `RadCheck` by following code

`radcheck.php`

```
namespace App\Model\Management;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Radcheck extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'radcheck';
    protected $primarykey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['id','username','attribute','op','value','barcode'];
    public $timestamps = false;
public function radusergroups(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Management\Radusergroup');
    }
}
```

Comment: i got it and not error. but i try, i cant login and displaying
"These credentials do not match our records."
i using "Value" field as "Password", how to change default authentication from field password to Value?

Comment: @muzamilindra directly you can not change password field. But you can specify your custom column name in your model class `public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password_column;
}`

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. yes i got it. i fixed and not error from register and login. but login default laravel with bcrypt encription, i want login without bcrypt process, because i remove bcrypt process on register controller..

Answer (score 1):

The model should extend `Authenticable`:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticable;

class Radcheck extends Authenticable
```

Comment: i got it and not error. but i try, i cant login and displaying "These credentials do not match our records." i using "Value" field as "Password", how to change default authentication from field password to Value?